# Fetching custom rest data from Django

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django as server side and angular as client side.

I want to fetch data from my django rest api backend.
I saw a lot of tutorials about fetching data from an already existent modules. But what if I want to retrieve data that is a combination of several modules?

For example, I have two modules Reservations and Clubs. I want to retrieve json object that contains data from both of these modules, for specific club id.

Modules -

```
class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    image_path = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

class Reservation(models.Model):
    club = models.ForeignKey('Club')
    user = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Serializers -

```
class ReservationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields  = ('club', 'user')

class ClubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Club
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'surfaces')
```

View sets -

```
class ReservationViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ReservationSerializer
    queryset = Reservation.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('id', 'club')

class ClubViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Club.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('id', 'name')
```

So, for this exmaple, I want that when I GET this url -
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/initial_data?club=2 
it will run a ViewSet that does some logic and then return a json of this format -

```
{club_id: 2, reservations: {1:"John", 2:"Doe", 3:"Bob"} }
```

And more generally speaking - How can I return my own custom json containing data from multiple modules, with given URL parameters (back to client side)?

EDIT - If I want to return a simple JSON, how should I do it with django DRF, considering the fact that each viewset is being mapped into a model/serializer?
Maybe using a simple JsonResponse..?

Answer (score 1):

You can define one serializer as a field in another

```
class ReservationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

class ClubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reservations = ReservationSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    ...
```

Now ClubSerializer will return Reservations inside each Club

Comment: Called [Nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Comment: @Serjik thanks for the quick reply. But I want to return a way more complex json from that one, that was just an example. I want to return data combined from multiple modlues

Comment: @John nop, enjoy to help

Comment: John: @Serjik answer is correct and points you in the right direction. If There's nothing that prevents you to return data models from other modules. It's in fact a common use case when you have a FK to User.

Comment: @Linovia Please refer my post edit. I want to return a json that contains many data types and values, not necessary Club and Reservations objects. Thanks again for your responses!

Comment: @john I'm sorry but I don't get what you're trying to do since you are mixin what you need and how you want to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `APIView` and override `get` method.

```
def get(self, request)

club = request.query_params.get('club', None)

"""
Do anything, access data, prepare dictionary or list with result
"""

return Response(result_dictionary_or_list)
```